# Disable layers (like roads) on map visualization in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I've created a really simple PowerBI report based on some dummy data in a CSV. It looks like this:

[image: powerbi map with lots of roads]

To repro my scenario just input any kind of map data like the single number shown above, and plot it in a map visualization with all the default settings.

The map has a *lot* of clutter, mostly caused by the roads and their names (and to a lesser extent by the city names). **Is there any way to disable layers in the map visualization?**

I've tried to answer my own question by:

- Going through all of the individual settings on the map visualization;
- Using some [Google-fu](https://www.google.nl/search?q=disable+roads+on+powerbi+map+visualization) to find my answer, skimming [the most promising result](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-tutorial-filled-maps-choropleths/) and a secondary [set of "tips and tricks"](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-tips-and-tricks-for-power-bi-map-visualizations/);
- Re-watching the appropriate parts of [the Pluralsight course on PowerBI](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/getting-started-power-bi/table-of-contents);

But haven't found a way to do this yet.

Am I missing something? Or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 1):

The default map/filled map visuals in Power BI are limited in terms of options such as decluttering the map (even compared to maps in Excel 2016).

One option (possibly the only one right now) is to use the ArcGIS maps, which you can enable under Options and Settings > Preview Features > ArcGIS Maps for Power BI. (It is a Preview Feature). Once enabled, you can select the visual at the end of your list of visualizations.

[image: Enabling ArcGIS maps in Power BI]

These do allow for finer-grained control. For example, you can click the In-Focus Edit Mode button at the top-right on the ArcGIS map and then choose Basemap to change to a gray map.

[image: Basemap Options in ArcGIS Power BI visual]

ArcGIS maps can also show a base layer, such as population density (which I think you had asked about in another question).

There are certainly some considerations when using this feature (it is a preview feature, and your data is going to Esri rather than Bing to be plotted).

Introductory Blog Post: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-arcgis-maps-for-power-bi-by-esri-preview/

More Information: http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-maps-for-power-bi

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I see where that feature is going, and it's an awesome new option, but it has several huge drawbacks. Most notably its deduplication doesn't work (or not nearly as well as the built in map), the city boundries are really awkward, it doesn't recognize several city names I tried, and AFAICT the saturation-based-on-value isn't available. - Again though, thanks a bunch for taking the time to write the extensive answer, much appreciated!

Comment: That's a great point (how Bing interprets & plots locations is going to be different to how ArcGIS does). I hope they don't abandon development on their own visuals in favor of ArcGIS.

Comment: If you're working with inconsistent location data, one word of warning I'd add is that if the map visual cannot plot a point, it doesn't get plotted. And sometimes a location can be plotted in the wrong location (if there are multiple places with the same name for example).

Comment: There's also an idea here you can vote on to improve the basic map styling options: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/15523362-map-styling

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've upvoted the linked "idea". - Related to the inconsistent data thing: I've found that the default map control breaks down pretty hard for my actual dataset. Guess I'll wait for a more mature version of that visualization.